# mapped file does not have a matching team identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, codesign

I used below script to resign app

```
codesign -f -s "Certificate Name" '--entitlements' 'entitlements.plist' applicationname.app
```

If I sign the app with same account certificate, then it installs.
If I sign the app with different account certificate, then it not installs.

find the logs below

```
Aug 27 18:43:12 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: xpcproxy[456] Container: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/39A5FAG2-47E3-452H-8B93-700493EGAF4B (sandbox)
Aug 27 18:43:12 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: AMFI: MyApp(pid 456) - [deny-mmap] mapped file does not have a matching team identifier: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7260C0G9-4290-453C-AA5B-A47CDE6273CD/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
Aug 27 18:43:12 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: AMFI: MyApp(pid 456) - [deny-mmap] process has team identifier 3G5GMTYJ2L: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7260C0G9-4290-453C-AA5B-A47CDE6273CD/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
Aug 27 18:43:12 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: AMFI: MyApp(pid 456) - [deny-mmap] mapped file has team identifier 9PN3V7LYI4: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7260C0G9-4290-453C-AA5B-A47CDE6273CD/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
Aug 27 18:43:12 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: AMFI: MyApp(pid 456) - [deny-mmap] mapped file does not have a matching team identifier: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7260C0G9-4290-453C-AA5B-A47CDE6273CD/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
Aug 27 18:43:12 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: AMFI: MyApp(pid 456) - [deny-mmap] process has team identifier 3G5GMTYJ2L: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7260C0G9-4290-453C-AA5B-A47CDE6273CD/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
Aug 27 18:43:12 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: AMFI: MyApp(pid 456) - [deny-mmap] mapped file has team identifier 9PN3V7LYI4: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7260C0G9-4290-453C-AA5B-A47CDE6273CD/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
Aug 27 18:43:12 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: AMFI: MyApp(pid 456) - [deny-mmap] mapped file does not have a matching team identifier: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7260C0G9-4290-453C-AA5B-A47CDE6273CD/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
Aug 27 18:43:12 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: AMFI: MyApp(pid 456) - [deny-mmap] process has team identifier 3G5GMTYJ2L: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7260C0G9-4290-453C-AA5B-A47CDE6273CD/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
Aug 27 18:43:12 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: AMFI: MyApp(pid 456) - [deny-mmap] mapped file has team identifier 9PN3V7LYI4: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7260C0G9-4290-453C-AA5B-A47CDE6273CD/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
Aug 27 18:43:12 iPad ReportCrash[457] <Error>: task_set_exception_ports(B07, 400, D03, 0, 0) failed with error (4: (os/kern) invalid argument)
Aug 27 18:43:12 iPad ReportCrash[457] <Notice>: ReportCrash acting against PID 456
Aug 27 18:43:12 iPad locationd[64] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
Aug 27 18:43:12 iPad ReportCrash[457] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process MyApp[456]
Aug 27 18:43:12 iPad com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.myapp.test[0xb1b7][456]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Aug 27 18:43:12 iPad ReportCrash[457] <Notice>: Saved report to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MyApp_2016-06-28-184312_iPad.ips
Aug 27 18:43:12 iPad SpringBoard[43] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.myapp.test[0xb1b7]' crashed.
Aug 27 18:43:12 iPad assertiond[58] <Warning>: Could not beset priority of <BKNewProcess: 0x1565bdd0; com.myapp.test; pid: 456; hostpid: -1> to 2, priority: No such process
Aug 27 18:43:12 iPad assertiond[58] <Warning>: Could not set priority of <BKNewProcess: 0x1565bdd0; com.myapp.test; pid: 456; hostpid: -1> to 4096, priority: No such process
Aug 27 18:43:12 iPad locationd[64] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
Aug 27 18:43:18 iPad locationd[64] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look into *entitlements.plist*.

It has the team identifier of your old account.

You have to update the team identifier with the team identifier of your new account and then sign the app.

You can find the team identifier by checking out the *User Id* of the certificate in Keychain or else

You can find it [here](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#accountSummary)

Comment: Thanks, +1 for the help, working for me... you saved my day.